# any API to change system date/time on WinCE

Tags: c#, windows-ce

any API to change system date/time on WinCE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used it, but there is a SetSystemTime function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms961527.aspx